# How to not capture vertical bar in regex?

Tags: regex

I have this regex

`([=|"| |_|\w]*)`, but regex101.com is telling me that `|` is one of the characters that's included in the group to be able to match, but I just want the characters `=` or `"` or  or `_` or `\w` to be matched.

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Use character class: `[=" _\w]*`

Comment: No need for the `|`. `[..]` contains all the relevant characters, not a literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?:=|"| |_|\w)*
```

You can use this.`|` inside `[]` is just a character without special meaning.

Comment: Characters sets are defined for this sole purpose. The fact that the accepted answer is one that explicitly enumerates makes for a terrible future reference...

Answer (score 4):

Inside a character sets (`[]`) `|` has no special meaning (it will match literally). In fact character sets have implicit **or** on their members. Just use `[=" _\w]*`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `([="\s_\w]*)`. It will match any of the combination of the elements.

> `[]` :  Matches a single character that is contained within the brackets

There is no need for `|` inside `[]`

Comment: I believe a character class will do this without the explicit `{1}`.

Answer (score 1):

no need for the `|`, inside of `[]` it is already *implied*

```
([="\s_\w]*)
```

^is basically the exact thing you are trying to do.

unless you meant this:

```
([=]|["]|[\s]|[_]|[\w]*)
```